# Python and Html - Producing Tables

Tags: python, html, list, html-table

I was wondering how you would get rid of the 'stray' box (circled in blue) that would be made from a 2 column table. This is what happens:[image: Table]

Here is my python code:

```
file_name = 'test.html'

test_file = open('test.html', 'w')

test_file.write('''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Dogs </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="5">
''')

dog_names = ['Bob', 'Kenny', 'Robin', 'Ben', 'Tom', 'Steve']
cat_names = ['Gob', 'Smith', 'Tod', 'Flamingo', 'Dragon', 'Fluffy']

index_dog = 0
index_cat = 0
amount = 5

for i in range(amount):
    if index_dog % 2 == 0:
        test_file.write('''          
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>''' + dog_names[index_dog]+ '''</p>
            </td>''')
    else:
        test_file.write('''    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>''' + dog_names[index_dog]+ '''</p>
            </td>
        </tr>\n''')
    index_dog += 1

for i in range(amount):
    if index_cat % 2 == 0:
        test_file.write('''          
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>''' + cat_names[index_cat]+ '''</p>
            </td>''')
    else:
        test_file.write('''    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>''' + cat_names[index_cat]+ '''</p>
            </td>
        </tr>\n''')
    index_cat += 1

test_file.write('''\n        </table>
    </body>
</html> ''')
```

HTML code produced by Python:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Dogs </title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <table width="500" border="2" cellpadding="5">

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Bob</p>
            </td>    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>Kenny</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Robin</p>
            </td>    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>Ben</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Tom</p>
            </td>          
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Gob</p>
            </td>    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>Smith</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Tod</p>
            </td>    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>Flamingo</p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>Dragon</p>
            </td>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I just found that if you give different values for dogs and cats (3 and 4), it will still create the odd box. How would I remove this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean exactly by "get rid of"?

Comment: Just removing the boxes with nothing in them, e.g. the 'gob' would go into the 1st blank box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a shared index between dogs and cats, to remember if you finish dogs on the left or the right

```
shared_index = 0
for i in range(amount):
    if shared_index % 2 == 0:
        test_file.write('''          
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>''' + dog_names[i]+ '''</p>
            </td>''')
    else:
        test_file.write('''    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>''' + dog_names[i]+ '''</p>
            </td>
        </tr>\n''')
    shared_index += 1

for i in range(amount):
    if shared_index % 2 == 0:
        test_file.write('''          
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>''' + cat_names[i]+ '''</p>
            </td>''')
    else:
        test_file.write('''    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>''' + cat_names[i]+ '''</p>
            </td>
        </tr>\n''')
    shared_index += 1
```

But you have six dog names and cat names. By limiting to 5, you will never see `Steve` or `Fluffy`

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to exclude Steve and Fluffy.

Comment: I just found that if you give different values for dogs and cats (3 and 4), it will still create the odd box. How would I remove this?

Comment: Joining the lists together avoids having special cases.

Comment: But wouldn't it still create a box with nothing within the table since it is an odd number.

Comment: Only at the end.

Comment: Is it possible to remove it?

Comment: Yes, don't assume the number of columns in your code, my second example doesn't assume, so will not draw any blank cells.

Answer (score 0):

In those two tr there are only one td, that is the reason you get those blank areas. Please add a td for each tr or add colspan="2" to the td.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just join the two lists and treat as a single list, e.g:

```
for i, name in enumerate(dog_names[:amount] + cat_names[:amount]):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        test_file.write('''
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>''' + name + '''</p>
            </td>''')
    else:
        test_file.write('''    <td align="center" align="center">
                <p>''' +  name + '''</p>
            </td>
        </tr>\n''')
```

If these were very long lists then I would recommend `itertools.islice()` and `itertools.chain()` vs adding the lists but for small lists this should be fine.

Personally, I would just iterate the list `2` at a time and template the string:

```
iterable = it.chain(it.islice(dog_names, amount), it.islice(cat_names, amount))
cols = 2
for names in iter(lambda: tuple(it.islice(iterable, cols)), tuple()):
    test_file.write('''
        <tr>
    ''')
    for name in names:
        test_file.write('''
            <td align="center" valign="center">
                <p>{}</p>
            </td>'''.format(name))
    test_file.write('''
        </tr>
    ''')
```

Comment: I'm just using very short lists to exemplify my problem, which is a bigger one. But this is good too.